# Empty record inserted when refreshing the data entry page

Tags: php

I am developing some web pages for a php project using CodeIgnitor. In a data entry form, every time I refresh the page (no data is entered to the form), an empty record is inserted to database, but I can't find why.
I was hoping that someone could give any help on this...

Thank you for your answers...

Comment: can u post the code that u used?

Answer (score 0):

If there is any `POST` request is sent to server you should redirect after processing the request otherwise the request will repeatedly be processed on every refresh.

You can use the header function fo this or can use the codeignitor's native redirect function.

```
header('loaction:somefile.php')
```

Comment: There was a mistake in the form action and all POST data were sent to insert method. So every time I refresh the page empty data were posted.Thank you again

Comment: hai..please suggest me..empty data was inserted when page refreshed in magento..how to overcome it..please help me